# meaning of ずっぽう

Tags: meaning, translation

What does zubbou mean in 当てずっぽう

Comment: https://wisdom-box.com/origin/a/ate-zuppou/　諸説あるようで

Comment: FWIW, the _Gogen Yurai Jiten_ entry seems to agree with that Wisdom Box link: https://gogen-yurai.jp/atezuppou/